# Child process creation in constructor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a class which creates a new process in constructor as below

```
class data_reader():
def __init__(self,paths_list,queue_limit = 1,parallel = True):
    print 'data reader constructor'
    self.paths = paths_list
    self.count = len(paths_list)
    self.async = async
    self.dict = {};
    self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(queue_limit)
    if parallel:
        self.child = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.load_paths,args = (self.paths,self.queue,))
        self.child.daemon = True
        self.child.start()
        print 'child started'
    else:
        self.load_paths(self.paths,self.queue)
```

this class has another function get_next() to get data from queue

```
def get_next():
        return self.queue.get()
```

This function is called form main like this

```
data_train = data_reader(train_paths_list)
data_valid = data_reader(valid_paths_list)
data_test = data_reader(test_paths_list)
```

Now in normal scenario whenever i run this code, it works fine and child processes are terminated as the objects get destroyed. The problem comes when i run this main as a child process from another program (spearmint https://github.com/JasperSnoek/spearmint ). The call for constructor does not ever return but a new child is created. In other cases the child is created but the message of

```
'data reader constructor'
```

is not printed and control is not returned to parent.

Is there some limitation that i am unable to understand.

PS. I am thinking to use socket programming to avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inherited my data_reader from Process as

```
class data_reader(multiprocessing.Process):
```

and refactored my class to override the run function from Process class. This solution worked in given scenario by calling start() from main